# Using context.InputParameters["Target"]

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I am creating a plugin for `Dynamics CRM 2011` to be executed when Qualifying a lead. I use this code

```cs
IPluginExecutionContext context = (IPluginExecutionContext)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IPluginExecutionContext));
IOrganizationServiceFactory factory = (IOrganizationServiceFactory)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IOrganizationServiceFactory));
IOrganizationService service = factory.CreateOrganizationService(null);
Entity curEntity = (Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"];
```

but when I get the `context.InputParameters["Target"]` it says that key not found. How can I get the lead entity when qualifying a Lead?

Answer (score 6):

If your plugin is executed on `QualifyLead` message (`Lead` as primary entity) you can get the reference to the lead in this way:

```cs
public void Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
    ITracingService tracingService = (ITracingService)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(ITracingService));
    IPluginExecutionContext context = (IPluginExecutionContext)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IPluginExecutionContext));
    if (context.InputParameters.Contains("LeadId") && context.InputParameters["LeadId"] is EntityReference)
    {
        EntityReference leadReference = (EntityReference)context.InputParameters["LeadId"];
        Guid leadId = leadReference.Id;
        // rest of your code
```

basically this message doesn't contain `Target` parameter, instead it contains `LeadId` parameter.

Comment: Is there any overview shows, which messages provied which InputParameters? At the moment im going to debug a plug-in and look for the given parameters.

Comment: Good question, but I never found a list of the possible inputparameters

Comment: I haven't found a good overview, but the definitive answer is in the MSDN article [Understand the data context passed to a plug-in](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309673.aspx#bkmk_inputandoutput): "the names of the actual public properties in the request." So look up the properties of your OrganizationRequest. In your case, the [QualifyingLeadRequest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.crm.sdk.messages.qualifyleadrequest_properties.aspx). You can see there is a LeadId property but no Target.

Answer (score 0):

I needed the name of the entity precisely because my same custom workflow was getting triggered on workflow for two different entities. Thus identifying the Target was necessary until i found "PrimaryEntityName".

`context.PrimaryEntityName` could be used in case someone is looking to identify which target entity the workflow was triggered on